# Do introverts and extroverts respond to dopamine and acetylcholine differently?

Tags: biology, psychology

This [Mind Brain Ed blog article](https://www.mindbrained.org/2020/02/embracing-the-introverted-brain/) is an example of one that quotes the book [*Quiet kids: Help your introverted child succeed in an extroverted world.*](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Quiet_Kids.html?id=tShBEAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) by Christine Fonseca in claiming that introverts and extroverts process neurotransmitters differently.

> One of the main differences between introverted and extroverted brains is how they respond to the neurotransmitter dopamine. [...] Extroverts have more dopamine receptors and are thus more likely to seek dopamine-releasing stimuli.
>
> [...]
>
> Introverts seek the comfort provided by a very different neurotransmitter. While dopamine provides excitement and rewards, acetylcholine provides introverts with calm and relaxation.
>
> [...]
>
> Christine Fonseca (2014) explained that acetylcholine works the same for introverts as dopamine does for extroverts. The difference is that introverts feel happiest when focused inside.

I do not have access to the the Fonesca book; I cannot see if the book made this claim, or the references to support it. I can't find evidence. The psychology papers I've read seem contradicting. I don't know what to believe anymore.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on extraversion and introversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraversion_and_introversion) has a detailed discussion of theories about the neurological basis of the difference between extroverts and introverts, with references. There is no mention of acetylcholine anywhere. Dopamine is mentioned once. I also found these two papers: [1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16289773/), [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3129862/). Again, they discuss dopamine but there’s no mention of acetylcholine anywhere.

Comment: Let's move this question away from what *you* may think, and focus on what the claimants claim.